# Yii1: How to force filter list in CGridView to parse html &nbsp;?

Tags: filter, html-encode, cgridview, yii1.x

I have a grid, in this grid I have filter. Grid code is:

```
$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'id' => 'sam',
        'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'responsiveTable' => true,
        'enableHistory' => true,
        'filter' => $asset,
        'columns' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'header' => '#',
                'filter' => false,
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'user',
                'header' => 'Registered By',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => '$data["assignedBy"]',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'createdAt',
                'header' => 'Created At',
                'type' => 'datetime',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'serial',
                'header' => 'Serial',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'brand',
                'header' => 'Brand',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'model',
                'header' => 'Model',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'assetType',
                'type' => 'text',
                'filter' => \wsi\it\model\AssetType::getRepository()->getTypeTree(),
                'value' => '$data["assetTypeName"]',
                'header' => 'Type',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'assigned',
                'value' => '(isset($data["assignedTo"]))? $data["assignedTo"]:null',
                'header' => 'Assigned To',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'location',
                'filter' => \wsi\hr\Facade::getInstance()->getLocations(),
                'value' => '$data["locationName"]',
                'header' => 'Location',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'status',
                'header' => 'Status',
                'filter' => \wsi\it\model\Asset::$statusOptionList,
                'value' => '\wsi\it\model\Asset::$statusOptionList[$data["status"]]',
            ),
            array(
                'class' => 'booster.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
                'template' => '{view}&nbsp;{update}&nbsp;{delete}',
                'header' => '',
                'buttons' => array(
                    'update' => array(
                        'url' => '\Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("asset/create", array("id"=>$data["id"]))',
                    ),
                    'view' => array(
                        'url' => '\Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("asset/view", array("id"=>$data["id"]))',
                    ),
                    'delete' => array(
                        'url' => '\Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("asset/delete", array("id"=>$data["id"]))',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

When Grid is rendered in the browser you can see that the filter list box contains html which is not parsed fully!

[image: I am talking about these $nbsp; in the filter list box]

I had this problem with Yii-Booster before and I solved it with an option which I passed to that widget ('htmlOptions' => **'encode' => false**) and It prevents   to be treated as string, so browsers would parse it as **space**. That code which You can see below does not work for grid filter!

```
$form->dropDownListGroup($formModel, 'segmentList', array(
        'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
            'class' => 'col-md-6'
        ),
        'widgetOptions' => array(
            'data' => $segmentTreeArray,
            'htmlOptions' => array(
           >>>  'encode' => false, <<<                    
            )
        ),
        'hint' => "Press CTRL to add another item, otherwise others will be deselected",
    ));
```

**BUT** I am sure that I have to pass same `"encode" => false` to filter list too, I just can not find under what key I should pass it (htmlOptions did not work).